# Handling File Uploads when a property is added from the Javascript File Object

Tags: javascript, php

When I [receive files via POST](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) I get the default `name`, `type`, `size`, `tmp_name`, `error` but the file I'm sending has additional information that I would like PHP to receive.

[image]

For example, above screenshot represents my file object in JavaScript. I added a property called `newName` which I would also like to receive in the global `$_FILES` variable in PHP, and then based on the newName property, upload the file on the newName.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you not use `name` property of `File` object?

Comment: @guest271314 I have a web application that allows to specify a new name for the file, and the file should be uploaded under the new name.

Comment: You can set the `name` property of the `File` object

Comment: @guest271314 No you can't it's read only.

Comment: You can create a new `File` object, pass the existing `File` object at the iterable and set the `name` at the new `File` object, see Answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `name` property of a `File` object at a new `File` object

```js
var file = new File(["abc"], "abc.txt", {type:"text/plain"});

console.log(file.name);

file = new File([file], "test", {type:file.type});

console.log(file.name);
```

Comment: Thanks! This works but now I lose the reference of the old name. It sucks that you cannot keep the relationship.

Comment: @Aaron `var fd = new FormData(); fd.append("fileName", "test"); fd.append("file", file);`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/Using_files_from_web_applications#Asynchronously_handling_the_file_upload_process

Comment: fileName will go to $_POST? (assuming a post request)

Comment: @Aaron Yes, you should be able to get the value using `$_POST["fileName"]`