# JavaScript not able to rename file before upload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload file to aws s3. before i upload i want to rename it by adding timestamp to file name. but i am geting an error as 'Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of object '#''

here is the code

```
let file = e.target.files[0];
let timeStamp = (new Date()).getTime();
let fileExt = file.name.split('.')[file.name.split('.').length-1];
let fileNameWithoutExt = file.name.replace(`.${fileExt}`,'');
let newFileName = fileNameWithoutExt + '_' + timeStamp + '.' + fileExt;
file.name = newFileName;
```

[image]

Comment: `name` is predefined property in `Object` object try to assign different property name like `fileName`

Comment: Related [Handling File Uploads when a property is added from the Javascript File Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48482524/handling-file-uploads-when-a-property-is-added-from-the-javascript-file-object/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- You can't change a name of an already created file.
- You can create
  new instance of file with new file name, like in a post above.But
  File constroctor is not supported by all browsers (is not supported at IE and EDGE [supporting table](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi)).
- You can put new
  file name to key property of your amazon upload
  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html

instead of `key = "folder1/folder2/${filename}"`
you can write `key = "folder1/folder2/youfilename.txt"`

Comment: Thanks @Alex. but i want to do it in browser itself.

Comment: @pratik-n Yes you can (create new file), but this will not work at IE and EDGE:)

Comment: @pratik-n Can you change key variable at browser side?

Answer (score 25):

Yep that sounds like a weird rule to set it as Read-only, but it's what it is...
So the workaround, not so hard, is to create a new File object from your previous one...

```js
var previous_file = new File(['foo'], 'file.txt', {type: 'text/plain'});
try{
  previous_file.name = 'hello.txt';
}
catch(e){}
console.log(previous_file.name); // didn't work

// so we just create a new File from it...
var new_file = new File([previous_file], 'hello.txt');
console.log(new_file);
```

But also note that if you need to support older browsers that don't support the File constructor, then you can override this file name in a FormData that you will send to your sever:

```js
var file = new File(['foo'], 'text.txt', {type:'text/plain'});
var formdata = new FormData();
// this will override the file name
formdata.append('file', file, 'hello.txt');
// and now you can send this formdata through xhr
// for demo, we will just log its content
for(let entry of formdata.entries()) {
  console.log(entry);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. Above IE 11 support is expected.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. Setting key variable for s3 params worked out for me. Your solution might help if not using aws s3.

Answer (score 15):

The append() method of FormData accepts a third optional filename parameter.

```
// new file name as a variable with timestamp
const newName = new Date().getTime() + event.target.files[0].name;  
fd.append('file[]', event.target.files[0], newName);
```

Comment: Simple and clean.